# Difficulty merging 2 x Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range) in one Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I've successfully written two macros to automate e-mailing based on cell values within a sheet (basically as a reminder system). The ranges overlap and one sub is intended to send an e-mail when cells reach a value of 0, the other is a smaller range of cells and is meant to send an e-mail when cells report a range between 1 and 5 (inclusive).

I can get the subs to work individually no problem, but my incredibly limited knowledge has been flummoxed when attempting to merge the two. Either it doesn't work at all, or it only part works.

If anyone could help me I'd be incredibly grateful as I'm at something of a loss! The code for the two subs is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("D122:D128,D131:D133,D138,D140,D144,D188,D191:D192,D217:D220,D294,D159:D167"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 0 Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 6 Then

            zRow = Target.Row
            zValno = Cells(zRow, "B")
            zValname = Cells(zRow, "C")
            zValInno = Cells(zRow, "D")

            Dim OutApp As Object
            Dim OutMail As Object
            Dim strbody As String

            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            strbody = ""
            strbody = strbody & "Please be advised that " & zValno & " (" & zValname & ") " & "is now low. This value is now " & zValInno & "."
            strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
            strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."
            strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
            strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."
            strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
            strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."
            strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
            strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."

            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .to = "abc@anyoldemail.com"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "LOW VALUE: " & zValno & " is now low."
                .Body = strbody
                .Attachments.Add ("C:\reportlog.txt")
                .Send
           End With
           On Error GoTo 0

           zSent = zSent + 1
           saywhat = "processing " & zSent & " of " & zCount
           Application.StatusBar = saywhwat
           Application.StatusBar = ""

           Set OutMail = Nothing
           Set OutApp = Nothing
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

And

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("D4:D100,G4:G100,J4:J99"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 1 Then

        zRow = Target.Row
        zValno = Cells(zRow, "B")
        zValname = Cells(zRow, "C")

        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        Dim strbody As String

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        strbody = ""
        strbody = strbody & "Please be advised that " & zValno & " (" & zValname & ") " & "is now reporting nil."
        strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
        strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."
        strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
        strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."
        strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
        strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .to = "abc@anyoldemail.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "NULL ALERT: " & zValno & " is now reporting nil."
            .Body = strbody
            .Attachments.Add ("C:\reportlog.txt")
            .Send
         End With
         On Error GoTo 0

         zSent = zSent + 1
         saywhat = "processing " & zSent & " of " & zCount
         Application.StatusBar = saywhwat
         Application.StatusBar = ""

         Set OutMail = Nothing
         Set OutApp = Nothing
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Since these ranges don't overlap why not just place the second intersect block after the first?

Comment: @glasfil  try the "Combined" code in my answer below, and see if it does what you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few modifications, try the combined code below for both `Worksheet_Change` events.

I've added a Variable `EmailType` that checks if the modified cells passed one of the 2 criteria’s, and then gets a value of 1 or 2.

Afterwards, according to the `EmailType` it modifies the email parameters.

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim mailSubject As String '<-- added this String variable to differ on 2 scenarios
Dim EmailType As Long '<-- use variable to see if passed the 2 criterias in the original code

EmailType = 0 '<-- init value
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("D122:D128,D131:D133,D138,D140,D144,D188,D191:D192,D217:D220,D294,D159:D167"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 0 And Target.Value < 6 Then
        EmailType = 1 '<-- Email Type = 1
    End If
End If

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("D4:D100,G4:G100,J4:J99"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 1 Then
        EmailType = 2 '<-- Email Type = 2
    End If
End If

If EmailType = 0 Then Exit Sub '< didn't pass any of the criterias >> Exit Sub

zValno = Range("B" & Target.Row)
zValname = Range("C" & Target.Row)

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Select Case EmailType
    Case 1
        zValInno = Cells("D" & Target.Row) '<-- this value exists on for Email Type 1
        mailSubject = "LOW VALUE: " & zValno & " is now low." '<-- mail subject for email type 1

        strbody = ""
        strbody = strbody & "Please be advised that " & zValno & " (" & zValname & ") " & "is now low. This value is now " & zValInno & "."
        strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
        strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."
        strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
        strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."
        strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
        strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."
        strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
        strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."

    Case 2
        mailSubject = "NULL ALERT: " & zValno & " is now reporting nil." '<-- mail subject for email type 2

        strbody = ""
        strbody = strbody & "Please be advised that " & zValno & " (" & zValname & ") " & "is now reporting nil."
        strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
        strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."
        strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
        strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."
        strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
        strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."
End Select

' ======= from here untill the end the same code, just using different values found per Email Type =======
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = "abc@anyoldemail.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = mailSubject
    .Body = strbody
    .Attachments.Add ("C:\reportlog.txt")
    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

zSent = zSent + 1
saywhat = "processing " & zSent & " of " & zCount
Application.StatusBar = saywhat
Application.StatusBar = ""

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I hadn't even considered this approach, so thanks for this. It's certainly a more elegant solution and not one I'd have thought of with my incredibly limited knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: @glasfil you're welcome, I had some free time yesterday :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the brute force approach, but I think your code could be shortened as there are commonalities

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("D122:D128,D131:D133,D138,D140,D144,D188,D191:D192,D217:D220,D294,D159:D167"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value > 0 Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 6 Then

            zRow = Target.Row
            zValno = Cells(zRow, "B")
            zValname = Cells(zRow, "C")
            zValInno = Cells(zRow, "D")

            Dim OutApp As Object
            Dim OutMail As Object
            Dim strbody As String

            Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

            strbody = ""
            strbody = strbody & "Please be advised that " & zValno & " (" & zValname & ") " & "is now low. This value is now " & zValInno & "."
            strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
            strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."
            strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
            strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."
            strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
            strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."
            strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
            strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."


            On Error Resume Next
            With OutMail
                .to = "abc@anyoldemail.com"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "LOW VALUE: " & zValno & " is now low."
                .Body = strbody
                .Attachments.Add ("C:\reportlog.txt")
                .Send
            End With
        End If
    End If

ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(Range("D4:D100,G4:G100,J4:J99"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    If IsNumeric(Target.Value) And Target.Value < 1 Then

        zRow = Target.Row
        zValno = Cells(zRow, "B")
        zValname = Cells(zRow, "C")

        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object
        Dim strbody As String

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        strbody = ""
        strbody = strbody & "Please be advised that " & zValno & " (" & zValname & ") " & "is now reporting nil."
        strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
        strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."
        strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
        strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."
        strbody = strbody & vbCr & vbCr
        strbody = strbody & "Blah, blah, blah."

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .to = "abc@anyoldemail.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "NULL ALERT: " & zValno & " is now reporting nil."
            .Body = strbody
            .Attachments.Add ("C:\reportlog.txt")
            .Send
        End With
    End If
End If

On Error GoTo 0

zSent = zSent + 1
saywhat = "processing " & zSent & " of " & zCount
Application.StatusBar = saywhwat
Application.StatusBar = ""

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah thank you, this is exactly how I tried to do it but I must have messed up somewhere along the way. With this I can now isolate the error I made in my initial attempt to merge the two, so not only does this solve my problem it's a valuable learning tool. Much obliged!

Comment: I wish I could mark two answers as having solved my problem as I feel both routes were very useful, this one helped me realise the error in my own coding while the other offered a new approach I hadn't considered. I've upvoted both (though I fear as a new user my upvotes don't actually show).